# Windows forms with SerialPort - app hangs after closing form

Tags: c#, multithreading, arduino, serial-port

I have a windows form application in order to connect to Arduino board. when I want to close it, it stays open until I stop debugging mode. this happens when I running program in Visual Studio and when I run `exe` file alone, I have to stop it from task manager.

I've tried to both `FormClosing` and `FormClosed` events but the result is the same. the only thing that crossed my mind is that this problems occurs because I used many `Invoke` functions for my controls in the `DataRecieved` event of my `SerialPort`. I've done this because I need thread-safe calls for my form controls. Here is some part of my code:

```cs
private void spArduino_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  if (spArduino.BytesToRead > 0)
  {
     string data = spArduino.ReadLine().Replace("\r", "");
     if (data.StartsWith("CUR_TEMP:"))
     {
         if (lbTemprature.InvokeRequired)
         {
            lbTemprature.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
               lbTemprature.Text = "Room temprature  " + data.Remove(0,9) + "°C";
             }));
         }
     }
  }
}
///////
 private void Monitoring_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
          spArduino.WriteLine("CLEAR");
          spArduino.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("errorclose");
     }
 }
```

And this shows up in my output (Visual Studio)

```
The thread 0x2bf0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5f24 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x46c4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5df4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x294c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4620 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x720 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x35a0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

And it stays this way until I stop the program.

Can anyone help me to understand where is my problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: Try to comment out everything in `spArduino_DataReceived`, run the app and try if it closes then. If yes, you've got an issue with your delegates. Guessing: `lbTemprature.Invoke` does not work correctly and the complete task in `spArduino` fails and blocks the UI then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SerialPort.DataReceived` event is triggered on a separate thread than the main UI thread, that's why you needed to call the `lbTemprature.Invoke` method when updating the UI.

#### Closing the form without closing the port

If you close the form without closing the port, then when closing the form, the `DataReceived` event may be triggered after the form disposed, which will cause an exception when trying to update the UI.

#### Closing the port before the form is closed

If you close the port before the form is closed (e.g. in the `FormClosing` event) than you may encounter a dead-lock because the `SerialPort.Close()` in the main UI thread waits for the thread that triggers the `DataReceived` event to complete the event, and the `DataReceived` event is waiting for the UI thread when you call `lbTemprature.Invoke`. This is probably what's causing the form to freez.

## Solution

A solution can be calling `lbTemprature.BeginInvoke` to avoid the dead-lock. This may not be enough, because the `BeginInvoke` can still run after the form is disposed and cause an expectation. Adding a check to the `Form.IsDisposed` property maybe needed.

```
if (lbTemprature.InvokeRequired)
{
    lbTemprature.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        if (!this.IsDisposed)
        {
            lbTemprature.Text = "Room temprature  " + data.Remove(0,9) + "°C";
        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into how you are cleaning up the serial device. Try unsubscribing from the event(s) (ie. `-= spArduino_DataReceived`). It is possible that references are preventing garbage collection and keeping your form alive after closing.